# An efficient way of making a large random bytearray

Tags: python, random, arrays

I need to create a large bytearry of a specific size but the size is not known prior to run time.  The bytes need to be fairly random.  The bytearray size may be as small as a few KBs but as large as a several MB.  I do not want to iterate byte-by-byte.  This is too slow -- I need performance similar to numpy.random.  However, I do not have the numpy module available for this project.  Is there something part of a standard python install that will do this?  Or do i need to [compile my own using C](http://docs.python.org/extending/)?

for those asking for timings:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('[random.randint(0,128) for i in xrange(1,100000)]',setup='import random', number=100)
35.73110193696641
>>> timeit.timeit('numpy.random.random_integers(0,128,100000)',setup='import numpy', number=100)
0.5785652013481126
>>>
```

Comment: Open `/dev/urandom`?

Comment: Python provides a portable interface to /dev/urandom: see my (second) answer.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The os module provides `urandom`, even on Windows:

```
bytearray(os.urandom(1000000))
```

This seems to perform as quickly as you need, in fact, I get better timings than your numpy (though our machines could be wildly different):

```
timeit.timeit(lambda:bytearray(os.urandom(1000000)), number=10)
0.0554857286941
```

Comment: Would just like to add that the random module can produce pseudo random data faster than `os.urandom`, at least on Linux.
-------------------------------------
`In [102]: timeit.timeit(lambda: bytearray(os.urandom(2**16)), number=100)`
`Out[102]: 0.03401689900783822`
---------------------------------
`In [103]: timeit.timeit(lambda: (random.getrandbits(8 * 2**16)).to_bytes(2**16, sys.byteorder), number=100)`
`Out[103]: 0.01772290701046586`

Comment: `os.random()` can block on Linux. See [PEP 524](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0524).

Answer (score 13):

There are several possibilities, some faster than `os.urandom`. Also consider whether the data has to be generated deterministically from a random seed. This is invaluable for unit tests where failures have to be reproducible.

short and pithy:

`lambda n:bytearray(map(random.getrandbits,(8,)*n))`

I've use the above for unit tests and it was fast enough but can it be done faster?

using itertools:

`lambda n:bytearray(itertools.imap(random.getrandbits,itertools.repeat(8,n))))`

itertools and struct producing 8 bytes per iteration

```
lambda n:(b''.join(map(struct.Struct("!Q").pack,itertools.imap(
    random.getrandbits,itertools.repeat(64,(n+7)//8)))))[:n]
```

Anything based on `b''.join` will fill 3-7x the memory consumed by the final bytearray with temporary objects since it queues up all the sub-strings before joining them together and python objects have [lots of storage overhead](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609).

Producing large chunks with a specialized function gives better performance and avoids filling memory.

```
import random,itertools,struct,operator
def randbytes(n,_struct8k=struct.Struct("!1000Q").pack_into):
    if n<8000:
        longs=(n+7)//8
        return struct.pack("!%iQ"%longs,*map(
            random.getrandbits,itertools.repeat(64,longs)))[:n]
    data=bytearray(n);
    for offset in xrange(0,n-7999,8000):
        _struct8k(data,offset,
            *map(random.getrandbits,itertools.repeat(64,1000)))
    offset+=8000
    data[offset:]=randbytes(n-offset)
    return data
```

### Performance

- **.84 MB/s** :original solution with `randint`:
- **4.8 MB/s** :`bytearray(getrandbits(8) for _ in xrange(n))`:  (solution by other poster)
- **6.4MB/s** :`bytearray(map(getrandbits,(8,)*n))`
- **7.2 MB/s** :`itertools` and `getrandbits`
- **10 MB/s** :`os.urandom`
- **23 MB/s** :`itertools` and `struct`
- **35 MB/s** :optimised function (holds for len = 100MB ... 1KB)

Note:all tests used 10KB as the string size. Results were consistent up till intermediate results filled memory.

Note:`os.urandom` is meant to provide secure random seeds. Applications expand that seed with their own fast PRNG. Here's an example, using AES in counter mode as a PRNG:

```
import os
seed=os.urandom(32)

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
backend = default_backend()
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(seed), modes.CTR(b'\0'*16), backend=backend)
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()

nulls=b'\0'*(10**5) #100k
from timeit import timeit
t=timeit(lambda:encryptor.update(nulls),number=10**5) #1GB, (100K*10k)
print("%.1f MB/s"%(1000/t))
```

This produces pseudorandom data at **180 MB/s**. (no hardware AES acceleration, single core) That's only **~5x** the speed of the pure python code above.

### Addendum

There's a pure python crypto library waiting to be written. Putting the above techniques together with `hashlib` and stream cipher techniques looks promising. Here's a teaser, a fast string xor (**42MB/s**).

```
def xor(a,b):
    s="!%iQ%iB"%divmod(len(a),8)
    return struct.pack(s,*itertools.imap(operator.xor,
        struct.unpack(s,a),
        struct.unpack(s,b)))
```

Answer (score 7):

What's wrong with just including numpy?  Anyhow, this creates a random N-bit integer:

```
import random
N = 100000
bits = random.getrandbits(N)
```

So if you needed to see if the value of the j-th bit is set or not, you can do `bits & (2**j)==(2**j)`

EDIT: He asked for byte array not bit array.  Ned's answer is better: `your_byte_array= bytearray((random.getrandbits(8) for i in xrange(N))`

Comment: This is nice.  Am i missing some obvious way of converting a long to a bytearray or bytebuffer?

Comment: Can't use NumPy because I am confined by my environment to a very limited number of external packages.

Comment: @Paul - Ned has the solution.  Sorry I suck at reading comprehension and misread it as bitarray.  If you want it as a oneliner you can do `bytearray((random.getrandbits(8) for i in xrange(N))`

Comment: KISS principle: don't import packages you don't actually need.

Answer (score 4):

```
import random
def randbytes(n):
    for _ in xrange(n):
        yield random.getrandbits(8)

my_random_bytes = bytearray(randbytes(1000000))
```

There's probably something in itertools that could help here, there always is...

My timings indicate that this goes about five times faster than `[random.randint(0,128) for i in xrange(1,100000)]`

Comment: See my timings.  I'm looking for an approx 30-100x speedup.

Comment: On the machine I'm writing from, using `random.getrandbits(8)` as drop-in replacement for `random.randint(0, 256)` is about 6 times as fast.